# jQuery UI Droppable items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**Hello**
I have a problem. The problem is, when I move an item to multiple slots it works perfectly.
But when i have two items of the same type, and I put them together it turns into a single item with the value of 2.
But I can't figure out how i could separate that two items into two separate items with the value of one.

```
                if($(this)[0].querySelector('.size').innerText > 1) {
                $(this).children().children().html(1);
            }
```

Project: https://codepen.io/KsenonAdv/pen/bGRaRjR

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour You may also want to edit your post and move the relevant code to your Post and not just link to a CodePen.

Comment: You will want to examine the Count when drag starts or when item is dropped and adjust the Count of the two items.

Comment: @Twisty But how i can replace the div in the next box?

Comment: There are going to be a number of ways to accomplish that. In Drag Start, you can check to see if the Count is greater than 1 and either Clone the drag item to be dropped.

Comment: @Twisty an example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function log(string) {
    console.log(Date.now(), string);
  }

  function makeGrid() {
    log("Make Grid...");
    for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
      $("<div>", {
        class: "slot"
      }).data({
        count: 0,
        stackable: true
      }).appendTo(".slots");
    }
    log("-* Grid Complete *-");
  }

  function makeDraggable(target) {
    log("Make Drag, Current Class: " + $(target).attr("class"));
    console.log(target);
    $(target).draggable({
      scroll: false,
      helper: "clone",
      cursor: "pointer",
      zIndex: 27,
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    log("After Make Drag, Current Class: " + $(target).attr("class"));
    console.log(target);
  }

  function refreshSlot(target) {
    log("Refresh Slot");
    $(".size", target).html($(target).data("count"));
  }

  function addItem(slot, item) {
    log("Add Item " + item.id);
    $.extend(item, {
      stackable: (item.category != 0),
      count: (item.count == undefined ? 1 : item.count)
    });
    slot = $(slot);
    var newItem = $("<div>", {
        class: "item",
        id: item.id,
      })
      .data(item)
      .css("background-image", "url(" + item.img + ")");
    newItem.appendTo(slot);
    $("<div>", {
      class: "size"
    }).appendTo(slot);
    slot.data({
      count: item.count,
      stackable: item.stackable
    });
    log("Item Added - Refreshing");
    refreshSlot(slot);
  }

  function emptySlot(target) {
    log("Empty Slot " + $(target).index());
    $(target).data({
      count: 0,
      stackable: true
    }).empty();
  }

  function loadPlayerItems(items) {
    log("Loading Player Items...");
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
      addItem($(".slots > .slot").eq(index), item);
    });
    log("-* Loading Complete *-");
  }

  function isAcceptable(item) {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0 || $(".item", this).data("stackable")) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  var pItems = {
    playerItems: [{
        img: 'https://i.imgur.com/5cjSI9X.png',
        name: 'bat',
        id: 1,
        category: 0
      },
      {
        img: 'https://i.imgur.com/HLQORBk.png',
        name: 'axe',
        id: 2,
        category: 1
      },
      {
        img: 'https://i.imgur.com/HLQORBk.png',
        name: 'axe',
        id: 3,
        category: 1
      }
    ]
  };

  makeGrid();
  loadPlayerItems(pItems.playerItems);
  makeDraggable(".item");

  $(".slots > .slot").droppable({
    accept: isAcceptable,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var origin = ui.draggable.parent();
      var target = $(this);
      log("Drop Accepted; From: " + origin.index() + ", To: " + target.index());
      // Increase the Count
      target.data("count", target.data("count") + 1);
      // Check for Stack
      if (target.children().length == 0) {
        addItem(target, ui.draggable.data());
      } else {
        refreshSlot(target);
      }
      // Check Orginal Stack
      if (origin.data("count") > 1) {
        origin.data("count", origin.data("count") - 1);
        refreshSlot(origin);
      } else {
        emptySlot(origin);
      }
      makeDraggable($(".item", this));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: url(http://img.playground.ru/images/5/1/GTA5_2015-05-07_00-53-36-07.png);
}

#inventory {
  height: 56.25vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.list-slots {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  max-width: 80%;
}

.slots {
  max-width: 87%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 3.125vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.slots .slot {
  width: 100px;
  height: calc(100px + 1em);
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 0.781vw;
}

.slots .slot .item {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="inventory">
  <div class="list-slots">
    <div class="slots"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As discussed in the comment, this updates the Count of items in the Slot by 1. When an items is dragged out, the count is lowered by 1.

To make things easier, I created a number of functions. You may choose to handle it in another manner if you like.